# Going Down fails when $R’$ is not an integral domain

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Here is an example of a ring extension, for which Going Down is not satisfied when $R’$ is not an integral domain. I need help justifying that Going Down is indeed not satisfied for these rings.

Let $R’=\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2-y, xy)$ and $R = \mathbb{C}[x]$. We know that $R \subset R'$ is an integral extension and that $R$ is normal. We want to check that for the ideal $(y-1)\subset R’$ the going down property is not satisfied. I want to summarise what I've done so far:

- Justified that $(y-1)$ is prime in R’.
- $(y-1)\cap R = (x)$.
- $(x)$ is prime in $R$.
- Considered the prime ideal $(0)\subset (x)$.

Now my question is: How can I prove/show that there is no prime ideal in $R'$ that lies over $(0)$? More explicitly, why is there no prime ideal $P'\subset (y-1)$ such that $P'\cap R = (0)$?

Comment: Is there a typo here? $R'$ as defined is a quotient of $R$, not an extension.

Comment: @TabesBridges You’re absolutely right. I meant to define R as $ \mathbb{C}[x]$. Thanks a lot for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that $\langle y-1\rangle$ is a minimal prime ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2-y, xy)$. To this end, let $P'$ be a prime ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2-y, xy)$ contained in $\langle y-1\rangle$. Note that $0=y(y-1)\in P'$, so either $y\in P'$ or $y-1\in P'$. If $y$ were in $P'$, then $1=y-(y-1)\in\langle y-1\rangle$, a contradiction. So $(y-1)\in P'$ and hence $P'=\langle y-1\rangle$.